# Einstein Box in context of Abraham-Minkowski debate

Tags: special-relativity, momentum, dielectric

A photon enters a box covered with anti-reflective coatings with total mass M, length L and refractive index n. My question concerns the application of the energy-momentum formula before the photon enters and when it is inside the box, working in the frame where the box is (initially) stationary. This thought experiment comes up in the literature when discussing the Abraham-Minkowski debate. The Abraham momentum is given by

$p = \frac{\hbar \omega}{c n}$

whereas the Minkowski momentum is given by

$p = \frac{\hbar \omega n}{c}$

In either case, we can setup the energy-momentum conservation equation before and after the photon enters the box:

$(\hbar \omega+Mc^2,\frac{\hbar \omega}{c},0,0) = (\hbar \omega+\gamma M c^2,p+\gamma Mv,0,0)$

My reasoning is that the energy of the photon remains $\hbar \omega$ inside the box. However, energy conservation then appears to force $\gamma=1, v = 0$. But if this is so, then momentum cannot be conserved whether we use the Minkowski or Abraham momentum! I must have made a blunder somewhere but I can't figure out what is wrong with this reasoning.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem just lies in the parametrisation of the energy-momentum 4-vectors.
$$
\begin{pmatrix}\hslash\omega+Mc^2\\\hslash\omega/c
\end  {pmatrix}=
\begin{pmatrix}\gamma Mc^2\\\gamma Mv
\end  {pmatrix}\qquad\bigwedge\qquad\frac vc=\frac{\hslash\omega}{\hslash\omega+Mc^2}
$$
Of course, if you still wanted to establish the photon propagating inside the system as separate from the rest of the system, then you need to have the correct expression for the energy of the photon. What you have essentially proved, is that $\hslash\omega$ is not the correct form of the energy of the photon when inside matter. That is the reason why you found that you could not conserve energy and momentum.

That is, it might be a fun exercise to try deriving the energy of a photon in medium, assuming either form of the momentum
$$
\begin{pmatrix}\hslash\omega+Mc^2\\\hslash\omega/c
\end  {pmatrix}=
\begin{pmatrix}E+\bar\gamma Mc^2\\p+\bar\gamma M\bar v
\end  {pmatrix}
$$
But it should be clear that this kind of reasoning is unlikely to settle the debate.

Comment: So is the Abraham-Minkowski controversy not just about the form of momentum, but also the energy? I'm also confused since the energy of a photon being hw in a dielectric is always taken for granted in physics, such as when talking about transitions between quantum states.

Comment: I do not want to feign knowledge on the matter but it does seem like the literature also covers the energy being different from $\hslash\omega$. The whole topic seems scary.